# Marquee is not working in spinner custom text xml

Tags: android, android-spinner, marquee

here is my layout_item.xml :

```
android:id="@+id/txt"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
android:gravity="left"
android:background="@drawable/spinner_line_box"
android:text="janak"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="@color/textColor"
android:textSize="16sp" />
```

and how i add is :

```
mAdapter_segment = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_dropdown, groupName);

spGroups.setAdapter(mAdapter_segment);
((ArrayAdapter) spGroups.getAdapter()).setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.layout_spinner_item);
```

Comment: text  should be bigger than screen width otherwise it will not work..

Answer (score 0):

Use requestFocus as well

```
 <requestFocus
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

and try with long text .